# Enable Ethernet in AOSP for Lollipop

Tags: android, android-source, ethernet

Does anyone know the steps required to enable Ethernet on Android Lollipop using the AOSP.  I found tutorials for ICS and KitKat but nothing for Lollipop.  I am using an IMX6 Nitrogen6x_MAX board.

Terminal commands are causing weird issues, so I want to try enabling Ethernet directly using the AOSP to see if that fixes it.

Thank you.

Comment: i am interested too, please keep me posted.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are lots of things to do. Good information from Android-Porting Google Group search for ethernet there, for example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-porting/ethernet|sort:relevance/android-porting/DWg67cTX5BE/3aPtzeZpBAAJ

Here's how you might get started...

Enable the correct ethernet driver in your Linux Kernel, for example:

```
CONFIG_USB_USBNET=y
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_EEM=y
```

Add the following to product `.mk` file:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.ethernet.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.ethernet.xml
```

Turn on DHCP and IP renewal in `init.rc`:

```
service dhcpcd_eth0 /system/bin/dhcpcd -ABKL -f dhcpcd.conf
    class main
    disabled
    oneshot

service iprenew_eth0 /system/bin/dhcpcd -n
    class main
    disabled
    oneshot
```

Update `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml` to include information about ethernet for connectivity, in `networkAttributes` string-array add:

```
<item>"ethernet,9,9,2,-1,true"</item>
```

**UPDATE:** This link may be useful as well https://github.com/gxben/aosp-ethernet